# 2 nos Peltier connection... Series or parallel

Tags: peltier

I'd like to build a mini AC using two Tec1 12706 Peltier modules. If I use two of them, should they be connected in series or parallel?

Can I use a 12VDC power supply that outputs 2A and takes 220VAC as input? Also, how do I assemble two of these Peltier modules?

Comment: Please add links to data sheets for all devices so that we don't all have to search for them.

Comment: @Supita I just ran 2 of those off of a 2576T - 12v swithcing voltage regulator in series. At 6v each they pulled like 2.6 ish amps. They hey hit 90 ish Celcius in a little under 5 minutes. They pull current based on the voltage input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect them in series or parallel, they will draw the same total power. If series, the PSU will need twice the voltage and half the current of a parallel configuration.

As Peltiers are very inefficient, they don't look a whole lot different from resistors, as far as the driver is concerned, so there is not the 'should I drive them as current or voltage'? issue that you get with LEDs and other such fussy loads.

Without you providing links to the module data sheets, there is little more that can be said.

Comment: Thank u so much. Can I placed the hotter side of two of them with 1 common heat sink? If yes then which cpu fan should I install for better cooling?  I will connect the colder sides with a common copper water block.

Comment: Yes, both the hotter and colder sides can be thermally paralleled. Which CPU fan??? Are you serious? Any adequate CPU fan! The one at the top of your junk box is worth connecting up to see how well it does, and whether it's adequate. If  not, then buy a bigger one.

Comment: Sir kindly suggest if I install two Tec 1 12706 peltier in parallel then an adaptor having 12 volt dc output with 2 amps curent will be suitable or not? If no then suggest the right adoptor.

Comment: @Sudipta  kindly post a link to the data sheet, and I'll read the current requirement from it, and multiply by 2

Comment: http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/313841/HB/TEC1-12706/27/1/TEC1-12706.html

Comment: @Sudipta At 12v they tend to draw about 4 to 5A. At 6v they draw around 2A. So put them in series, and you might just be able to drive them. Are you sure you want to drive two of those devices from as little as 24watt PSU? What are your cooling specifications, for deltaT, cooling power and COP (Coefficient of Performance)?

Comment: @Sudipta this is a rather better data sheet, check out the COP curves! http://www.thermonamic.com/TEC1-12706-English.PDF

Comment: Sir I am not an electronics expert. So I dont have such depth on that.

Comment: @Sudipta sorry to disabuse you but cooling power and deltaT are thermal specifications, not electrical specifications. If you are just playing with these things to see what they do, then fine, you don't have a specification to meet. If you are trying to build a fridge, or a CPU cooler, then you should ideally have a thermal performance specification. Without that, it would be easy to build something that did not do what you needed it to do.

Comment: Sir here I am forwarding a link to clarify what I want to make.... Its a you tube video link. In that video the owner showed he is using a single tec 1 12706. The only thing I want to modify is using of two numbers same tec instead of one. All other component will remain same. Thats why I asked which dc adapter should I use?? Sir here is the link.... https://youtu.be/4GdEDalMjpQ

Comment: Sir actually we dont have enough money to buy a real ac from shop. Thats why trying to solve the purpose to make my family happy... In summer we face lots of trouble. So I am trying to make this....

Comment: @Sudipta sorry, you are out by an order of magnitude or two if you want AC for rooms. But, you can cool some water, and a few cool drinks a day might make them happy. Put them in series for 6v each, current consumption would be 2A or a little more, might need a larger supply. It will be far cheaper and higher performance if you want a low cost hacked AC to get a standard compressor-type fridge, and shroud and fan the heat exchanger to vent entirely outside. Still too small by an order of magnitude, but 10x better than a TEC!

Comment: Sir one more thing, at the time of setting a cooler fan with the heat sink, which direction should I place the fan?? I mean allow air coming from out side to cool the heat sink or to suck the hot air out of heat sink... which is better?

Comment: @Sudipta Commenting on that youtube video: the water-circuit is not only completely redundant, it's harmful, as the power consumed by the water pump reduces the efficiency of the installation. Better to put a small CPU cooler fan on the cold side, and a big one on the hot side, and have it all air to air. I didn't watch it all the way through, does it say to duct the hot air from the hot side to outside the dwelling? This is necessary. If the humidity is low enough, better to build a 'bong' water chiller outside, needs only a few watts for a water pump and fan (google for bong chiller)

Comment: @Sudipta when fully ducted, blow or suck makes little difference. Typical CPU fans are not fully ducted, and I've always seen them blow, never suck, and I imagine there's a reason for that. There's bound to be more turbulence, which improves heat transfer, downstream of the fan than upstream. Follow the crowd and blow from fan to heatsink.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable guidance sir... If I install a small fan on colder side should it be done with another heat sink or without?

Comment: @Sudipta a 'CPU cooler fan' consists of a small fan clipped on to a heatsink. You need both to be efficient. You need the large fin area of the heatsink to get good coupling of heat from metal to air, you need the metal contact to the TEC to get good coupling of heat from the TEC into the heatsink. Simply blowing a fan onto the cold face of the TEC results in very poor heat transfer.

Comment: That means I have to set two heat sinks, one at cold and other at hot side right?